# Data Transfer Object DTO Where to build

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dto

Trying to refactor some code. I see some classes creating DTO objects which are being passes in the service layer and returned later by the @RestController. As I know it is best to build the Data Transfer Objects only in the controllers and pass them to the views, especially when we use something like `WrapperDTO<T>` with get and set value. Maybe there are differences when we are building the WrapperDTO with complex object or simple data types. All oppinions will be well appreciated.

Comment: I think You should look at [Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/277817/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-dtos-from-entities-and-update-entities-from-dtos)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

DTO may be used to transfert data between the different layers of an application: DAO, Service, Facade, Controller. In my experience DTO is an opinionated topic.

In my opinion, the later the conversion, the better, it is even better if no conversion is needed. Generally, the later is at the application boundary. DTO is not free, it involves mapping and its support. Hence DTOs will make sense when there is a domain model mismatch or a model technical mismatch accross the boundary. For more information you can have a look at [LocalDTO article and the associated link](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/LocalDTO.html).

If I focus on the *service* -> *facade* -> *controller* layers:

- **Services:** They are doing services things and they may call each other to do their processing. If your domain models remain consistent across the services boundary `service => facade` it is too early to convert the result into a DTO.
- **Facades:** They may orchestrate services and convert input/output. In my point of view it will be the right place to convert to or from DTO. But only if it is needed to ie. because your domain models have to be transformed accross this boundary (filtering fields, aggregation...)
- **Gateway/Controllers:** They are at the application boundary. Their logics are simple, reduced to the boundary logic. The relation between a facade and a controller is usually `one <-> one`. ***

  ***Merging facades and controllers usually make sense***

---

Thus in my point of view, your first proposal is more adapted eg. `UserController....`. The most important is to stay pragmatic.

Comment: A nice, balanced answer. I wrote a couple of posts on DTOs and Domain Objects, largely with the same conclusion. https://notesofapragmaticprogrammer.wordpress.com

Answer (score 5):

I would say it's better to create DTO on Service layer.

Controller must not know business logic details. E.g. we need to return User info but some fields (password etc.) must be excluded. The fields exist in the User entity but must be removed from DTO.

Another case we got `SomePaginationDTO` on Controller and we still need to pass the DTO to service to parse filter, apply sort, limit results etc. All the logic is part of service responsibility. So I would pass the `SomePaginationDTO` to service.

Comment: I have mixed thoughts. I totally agree about SomePaginationDTO, I use dynamic DTO (Map) and can even ask "some fields only" to service (in a similar way to sort,filter,paging). If I want 'user-no-password' I use this mechanism. Alternatively I get an Entity (or full DTO) from service in controller and make the "(dynamic) dto without password" in controller. If  I hadn't the fields-selection mechanism I wouldn't create a getUserNoPassword() method on service, I would do the transform to DTO in controller. I am not sure this is business logic, to me seems more controller-view logic. Am I wrong ?

Comment: For me controller should not know how to restrict data or how full should be returned data. It's part of service IMHO. Controller's responsibilities is data transfer (marshall unmarshall), security checks, filtering, error handling.

Comment: Thanks. But if the service does not implement selecting columns ? Or, maybe more common: if the service does not implement sorting or paging, where do you do the in-memory sorting or paging ? I do it in the controller and in the same way I do property/column selection when not supported by service. It could be also a UI functionality only, possibly a per-user preference. I would really like to hear an opinion on this.

Comment: @TestoTestini yes, the column selection, sort etc. could be UI only. But if amount of results is significant (let's say >10K) it's really hard to get all the data on UI. In the case it's better to do this on service/db layer. Additionally service can do some aggregation which could be hard on UI.

Comment: 10k seems a fair amout, after that I would consider mirroring the source in DB. I think that the controller, like it marshalls service-data to json, it does the same with the view, sending to it what it needs (user without password). Ideally the two data would be the same but this is other argument. If the service can be asked some columns controller uses the service, otherwise it does it by itself copying the entity to a DTO. In reality is hard to do it because of little support. I am rather extreme in this as my service does also grouping "on-demand" so that also aggregation becomes "UI".

Answer (score 1):

I would say there is no canonically right way to do this. It depends on what is DTO used for.

I found a simple rule for myself on where to use DTO in service level and where to not: **In case if service level has only one client I use DTO across service level. In case if there are two or more clients it is better not to use DTO in service level.**

Let me explain this in more details:

Basically it is clear that not including DTO into service level requires more efforts. So in case if there is only one client I would keep things simple and use DTO as a return type for service methods.

In case if there are more then one client of the service most likely the clients will require different DTO (for instance I want to have `json` and `csv` representation of an object). In such case I will not return DTO from service. Otherwise I would need to have different services for each DTO, or different service methods, etc.

**Note:** I'm not saying that if you don't use DTO in service level you must move the transformation logic into controller level. I still think that controller level must be as simple as possible. You might have some intermediate transformation level between controller and service - uncomfortable, but it is much better then having several services.

Answer (score -1):

I found a great answer as a part of other question. Of course this/my answer does not participate for the bounty. It is just an inspiration someone to explain how the things are implemented nowadays. So take a look:

- Model classes. They don't get getters/setters for everything. It
  depends on model logic. Otherwise you get model where you can easily
  break consistency. Or where are many unobvious things. Suppose you
  have User.registrationDate field. When you construct a new User
  object, you should not forget to field registrationDate field by
  hands. So, just place registrationDate initialization in your
  constructor and remove setter!
- Repository interface just inside your model. Suppose you have some
  business logic that depends on existing stored objects. You can't
  expliciltly refer from your domain logic into infrastructure
  dependencies like JPA, Hibernate, JDBC, etc. So you query this stored
  objects from interfaces.
- Business services (optionally). They implement some complex logic,
  involving many different entities, not including security and
  transaction management. Your question is about it. Yes, if you need
  query for entities in your domain logic, place query into repository
  and call it from your business service.
- Repository implementation inside infrastructure package. Implements
  repository interfaces using JPA or mockito or whatever else. They
  also don't include neither security nor transactions.
- Application services (optionally). If there is some complex
  interaction with infrastructure or security checking.
- Remote facade interface. Client and server communicate only through
  remote facade interface.
- Remote facade implementation (controller). Transforms thick entity
  objects into thin DTOs (data transfer objects). All transaction
  demarcation and security is here (often using annotations).

*What do you think about that design? Is it applicable for the well know spring mvc?*